# FocusLost being called twice

Tags: lua, roblox

Whenever I use FocusLost on a TextBox, its called twice for some reason

Code:

```lua
script.Parent:WaitForChild("CommandBar").Command.FocusLost:Connect(function(enterPressed)
    print("FocusLost")
    -- My code
end)
```

FocusLost is printed into my console TWICE. Is this supposed to happen?

Answer (score 0):

Found my answer, there are multiple instances of the handle script. Weird